# Dart: Why instances created are not identical but variable accessed by them is?

Tags: dart

As you can see `animal1` and `animal2` are two different instances, but why the `animal1.age` and `animal2.age` are identical? Doesn't Dart create separate copies of these variables?

```
class Animal {
  int age = 10;

  Animal();

  Animal.named();

}

void main() {
  var animal1 = Animal();
  var animal2 = Animal.named();

  print("${identical(animal1, animal2)}"); // prints false
  print("${identical(animal1.age, animal2.age)}"); // prints true

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart integers are considered identical if they are equal. There are not two different versions of the integer `10`, so when you ask `identical(animal1.age, animal2.age)`, you are really just checking whether their integer age is the same value.

The *variables* are different, they just happen to hold the same (equal and identical) value, which is what you check.

Comment: Thanks Irn once again, but I read somewhere everything in Dart is object, so I thought `identical(animal1.age, animal2.age)` doesn't mean we are checking `animal1.age == animal2.age1`.

Comment: All values are objects. Variables are not objects, so you are not checking whether it's the same `age` variable, only whether it's the same value stored in the two `age` variables. The value `10` *is* an object. It just happens that there is only one integer object with the value 10, so it's the same object that is stored in both `age` variables.